# Standards for writing grammar file for sphinx 4

Tags: cmusphinx

I want to write grammar file for speech recognition system. I am using sphinx 4 for doing that. But i am confused with the syntax of writing grammar file. I have tried to search it out how to write gram file but i am unable to find it out. Can anyone provide me a link for writing grammar file standards and syntax for it??

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/

Comment: thnx dude...:). I want this badly.